# How to add userName who execute the report in birt

Tags: birt

I used to develop report in SSRS and a newbie in birt, there're a bunch of handy global functions in SSRS that can be used but can't be found in birt.
I tried to develop a report that needs to show the sysuser who are executing the report but can't find an easy way to implement it in birt.
Can anyone suggest me an easy way to do it? Do I need to install Maximo and use para userName?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What version of BIRT are you using, and how are the users getting access to the reports?

Comment: I downloaded the most recent version. I am currently in the designing phase. Actually I am building a template for late use. In the template I'd like to show: Welcome UserName, execution time on the upper right corner of the report, for execution time I can use the auto text in the palete "Created on", I thought "created by" will show the person who executed the report but it's totally something else. At this point I have no clue how to show the Username who execute the report.Here's the birt version :Eclipse Report Designer Version 4.3.2.v20140211-1400

Answer (score 0):

You can use following JavaScript:

```
Packages.java.lang.System.getProperty("user.name")
```

This will run Java method `System.getProperty("user.name")` which returns current user.

Comment: Thank you! Kazik Will try and let you know

Comment: Old thread, but for anyone coming here , Add a dynamic text, then in expression builder eval(Packages.java.lang.System.getProperty("user.name")). You get the user name on the CLIENT machine, not the server.